# Flow Document in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, flowdocument

I am creating a Google Books reader app for Windows Phone 8 that uses the Google Books API for fetching the data. I want to use a flow document kind of appearance while a user goes through the pages of the books. As far as I have searched till now, I've got to know that flow documents are not supported in Windows Phone 8. Just wanted to know if there is any way to use Flow Documents in Windows Phone 8 ?

Comment: What do you mean by "flow document". Could you describe what type of layout you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks! What I meant was a FlipBoard kind of thing where you flip pages of a book. That kind of flow can be acheived by some level of animation. Anyways, I got my answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

U can refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.section.aspx).. According to this link windows 8 is also supporting Flow Document.